# How are complex sample analysis and GEE different from each other?

Tags: sampling, generalized-estimating-equations

I am currently analyzing a national survey data. The survey design is complex: 1) strata 2) cluster 3) 2-stage, 4) sampling weight. There are strata; PSUs(agencies) were selected randomly and systematically within each stratum. Then, observations (persons) were randomly selected from each PSU. There is dependency within PSUs among observations judged by the sample design (nesting) and evidenced by ICC.

I am conducting a logistic regression using the data. My questions are:

1) How does a standard complex sample analysis (provided by stat packages such as STATA (svy) or SPSS (complex samples)) treat within cluster dependency differently from a generalized estimating equations?

2) Are resultant coefficients (odds ratios) and SEs supposed to be almost same for both approaches (When I use independence correlation matrix for GEE, the result is almost     identical to standard complex sample analysis. However, when I use exchangeable correlation matrix, the results (odds ratios and SEs) are moderately different - I mean one predictor becomes non-significant and ORs become double for a few predictors).

3) What can be the reasons for choosing GEE over complex sampling data analysis? In other words, what criteria to use to choose one over the other?

I am using STATA for the analysis. Thank you.